# Jquery code only works sometimes with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm not able to get my jquery code to work with my Bootstrap 4. div.

My goal is to have two divs (fluid bootstrap containers) in the banner section, however one showing upon loading the page for about 5sec. and then gradually fading out while the next div gradually fades in.

I'd appreciate your help and if possible an explanation why my second block of code won't work.

PS: I know that the 2nd code block does not represent my goal, but it should also work and does not.

This works:

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    $('#div-a').replaceWith($('#div-b'));
    $('#div-b').show();
  },
  4000
);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
       setTimeout(function(){
$("#div-a").fadeOut("slow", function () {
$('#div-a').replaceWith($('#div-b'));
$('#div-b').show();
});
}, 2000);
```

In my CSS file I have the following:

```
#div-b {
display: none;
}
```

In my HTML file I have the following:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <title>TEXATREK</title>
</head>
<body>



  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navi">
    <a class="navbar-brand"  href="">
      <img class="brand-logo" src="images/logos/Trexatek_Logo_AND_Name_Gold-Orange.png" alt="">
    </a>

    <!--HAMBURGER Toggler Icon-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- NAVBAR  -> div BELLOW -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-5 ">
        <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">Users</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">Items</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">Pigis</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="">Rolls</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!-- SECTION 1 -->
 <!--WELLCOME PAGE SECTION-->
  <div id="div-a" class=" mt-2 px-0 pt-05 container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="hex-container mx-0 px-0 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <img class="hex-banner img-fluid" src="images/Banner/Hexagon-Banner/Hexagon_Photo_Grid_with_logo_in_middle 1915x615.png" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

<!--REPLACEMENT AFTER 5 SECONDS -- START-->

  <div id="div-b" class=" mt-2 px-0 pt-05 container-fluid">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="hex-container mx-0 px-0 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
          <h1>SIGN UP NOW BITCHES</h1>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

<!--REPLACEMENT AFTER 5 SECONDS -- END-->

  <!-- SECTION 2 -->
  <!--INFORMATION ABOUT TEXATREK 1. US 2.OUR STRENGTH 3. WHY TEXATREK-->
  <div class="container-fluid pt-5">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="mx-0 px-0 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

           <!--WHAT WE DO info section-->
           <div class="texatrek-info what-we-do">
              <h2>WHAT WE DO</h2>
              <h3>Our company specializes in sourcing precision components that are manufactured in India by our network of carefully selected, high quality suppliers, all of which are ISO 9001 certified. Our goal is to ensure reliable supplies at competitive costs and with zero defects.</h3>
          </div>
          <!--OUR STRENGTHS info section-->
          <div class="texatrek-info our-strengths">
                <h2>OUR STRENGTH IS YOUR ADVANTAGE</h2>
                <h3> We manage and expand our carefully selected Indian supplier base to meet the ever-growing demand of our customers. By offering a broad selection of manufacturing technologies we are able to support you to meet the challenges you are facing in terms of design and supply chain, that is optimized for manufacturing and thus resulting in reduced unit cost. </h3>
          </div>

          <!--BACKGROUND IMAGE HEXAGONS-->
          <div class="product-background">
            <img class="img-fluid product-background-img" src="images/Background/Background-info_cropped.png" alt="">
          </div>-

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

<!-- SECTION 3 -->
<!--PRODUCTS AND SERVICES SECTION-->
  <div class="container-fluid pt-5">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <img id="products-services" class="img-fluid"src="images\Info_Graphics\Products and Services.png" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="solutions-container">
          <!--THE BLACK IN THE BLUE BLOCK (div)-->
          <div class="solutions-inside">
              <h3 class="solutions text-left">SOLUTIONS SOLUTIONS SOLUTIONS THAT FIT</h3>
            <h5 class="solutions-para text-left">paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- SECTION 4 -->

  <div class="container-fluid pt-5">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TrexatekNavbar_V3_Bootstrap.css">

  <script>

    $('#div-a').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
    $('#div-a').replaceWith($('#div-b'));
    $('#div-b').fadeIn('slow');
});

/*    
setTimeout(function(){
$("#div-a").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $('#div-a').replaceWith($('#div-b'));
  $('#div-b').show();
});

}, 2000);

    setTimeout(
      function() {
        $('#div-a').replaceWith($('#div-b'));
        $('#div-b').show();
      },
      4000
    );
    */

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Review the order of your references. and the requirements on the bootstrap 4 documentation page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replaceWith() while elements fadeOut() and fadeIn() in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870225/replacewith-while-elements-fadeout-and-fadein-in-jquery)

Comment: I tried this code:
`$('#div-a').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
    $('#div-a').replaceWith($('#div-b'));
    $('#div-b').fadeIn('slow');
});`
But no luck

Comment: @crying Freeman
I think the order should be fine see comments bellow in response to Parth Lukhi